# Unity, Scene and ScriptableObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried using ScriptableObject to store data about levels, currently, there are these properties:

```
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Score;
    public bool IsCompleted;
    public bool IsLocked;
    public Scene Scene;
```

As you can see there's Scene reference. In Unity Editor this looks like this:
[image]

It seems that I can't (or can, maybe I just don't know it yet) reference Scene in there, instead, I have some sort of `Handle` property, I couldn't find any reference to this in Unity Scripting API.

What's this? How can I store reference to the Scene in there?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your Scene class look like?

Comment: It's native Unity Scene class.UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Might be easier to just store the Scene name and then load the details of the Scene when needed.

Comment: Yeah, but it would be amazing to Store the Scene itself, but now I am REALLY curious what's that? Handle? Why I can;t store it like that?

Comment: The handle is just a reference to the Scene.  If you are trying to programmatically save the Scene at runtime what are you trying to do with it at design time in Unity Editor?

Comment: I wanted to store it in ScriptableObject with other properties, like `isLocked`, `isCompleted`, `score`. So later I would just take this data and, if needed, load the scene. I could store just build index or name/path, but why not store the whole Scene?

Comment: Ok, you don't really need a public property to be able to set this in the Unity Editor at design time then.  You'll only be setting it in code at runtime so best practice is to make that property private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that's impossible to do. And here's the *right* way to do it:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneAsset.html